# How can I show shipping methods and rates on a CMS page?

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, quote, shipping-methods

I am trying to add shipping estimates onto a CMS page in Magento to display shipping methods, estimated shipping delivery dates and rates etc...

I have a module (meanbee estimated delivery) which gives me access to this information in the the Shipping step of the checkout page but I would also like to display the values on a CMS page.

Here is what I have so far:

I have created a CMS page called shipping-delivery and added this to the content

```
{{block type="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available" template="meanbee/estimated_delivery/cms/cms-available.phtml"}}
```

then inside of my cms-available.phtml file I have

```
<?php $_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates(); ?>
<?php if (!$_shippingRateGroups): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <dl class="sp-methods">
        <?php $shippingCodePrice = array(); ?>
        <?php $_sole = count($_shippingRateGroups) == 1; foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <?php $_sole = $_sole && count($_rates) == 1; foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <?php $shippingCodePrice[] = "'".$_rate->getCode()."':".(float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?></li></ul></li></ul>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php if ($_sole) : ?>
                                    <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" checked="checked" /></span>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>

                                <?php if ($_rate->getCode() === $this->getAddressShippingMethod()): ?>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        //<![CDATA[
                                        lastPrice = <?php echo (float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>;
                                        //]]>
                                    </script>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </label>
                                <!-- START MEANBEE ESTIMATED DELIVERY -->
                                <br/><?php echo Mage::helper('meanbee_estimateddelivery')->getEstimatedDeliveryText($_rate->getCode()); ?>
                                <!-- END MEANBEE ESTIMATED DELIVERY -->
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        <?php if (!empty($shippingCodePrice)): ?>
        var shippingCodePrice = {<?php echo implode(',',$shippingCodePrice); ?>};
        <?php endif; ?>

        $$('input[type="radio"][name="shipping_method"]').each(function(el){
            Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){
                if (el.checked == true) {
                    var getShippingCode = el.getValue();
                    <?php if (!empty($shippingCodePrice)): ?>
                    var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];
                    if (!lastPrice) {
                        lastPrice = newPrice;
                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;
                    }
                    if (newPrice != lastPrice) {
                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);
                        lastPrice = newPrice;
                    }
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is I get this message when I browse to my cms page:

```
Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.
```

I'm not sure what I am missing out so could do with a nudge if anyone can help me out?

Comment: As a suggestion - have you thought about doing it on a business level and keeping it simple with a flat rate building it in to the margins - this is how the large enterprise companies do it as it reduces workload and simplfies customer experience. That way there is no technology involved.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that problem is here:

```
<?php $_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates(); ?>
```

For me you don't have method `getShippingRates` in `core/template` block, maybe you must call proper block from your module, not from magento core.

Comment: Thank for your comment, I'm now using `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available` But I still get the message :( Not sure which block to use here...

Comment: There should be block from meanbee estimated delivery extension. Search for method getShippingRates() in extension blocks.